# Android with eclipse proguard.cfg problems

Tags: android, eclipse, compiler-errors

My application works fine until now.

I'm getting error like

```
Obsolete proguard file; use -keepclasseswithmembers instead of -keepclasseswithmembernames proguard.cfg
```

I haven't touched proguard.cfg file.

I have already cleaned my application and also reopened my application. Without luck.

Any ideas?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug with the SDK tools v11. 
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=16384

When Lint generates error,

- go to lint warnings view (Window > Show View > Other > android > Lint Warnings) and double     click the error to modify proguard.cfg
- rename "keepclasseswithmembernames" to "keepclasseswithmembers" on line it shows error and save.
- run Lint again (click refresh in Lint Warnings view)
- repeat renaming if it shows further warnings in subsequent lines.

I changed mine to look like this.

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}
```